# Parse data format in C

Tags: c, char, printf

I am new in C so I have never done that before. 
What I am doing is open a file, parse the data and print the result in another file.
Assume that the file open (in the main function) was ok and now I use strtok() function to break the string in tokens.

Using the above function I get an output file like this:

```
{"date": "11:20:50.359", "date": "08-02-16"}
```

But what I would like is to get the data:

```
{"date": "11:20:50.359 08-02-16"}
```

This is my code:

```
void tokenize( char *oneline, FILE *fileName){

   const char delimiter[6] = DELIMITER__;
   char *token;
   int counter = 0;

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(oneline, delimiter);

   char time_str[50];
   char date_str[50];

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) { 

     if (counter == 1 ){
    char * strA = "\"", * strB = ":", str[50], strC[50], strD[50];
    int v = 0, x = 3, y = 6, z=13;

    strncpy(str,token,v);
    str[v] = '\0';
    strcat(str,strA);
    strcat(str,token+v);

    strncpy(strC,str,x);
    strC[x] = '\0';
    strcat(strC,strB);
    strcat(strC,str+x);

    strncpy(strD,strC,y);
    strD[y] = '\0';
    strcat(strD,strB);
    strcat(strD,strC+y);

    strncpy(time_str,strD,z);
    time_str[z] = '\0';
    strcat(time_str,strA);
    strcat(time_str,strD+z);    

        fprintf(fileName, "%s", "\"date\": ");
        fprintf(fileName,"%s, ", time_str);
     }

     if (counter == 9 ){ 
    char * strA = "\"", * strB = "-", str[50], strC[50], strD[50];
    int v = 0, x = 3, y = 6, z=9;

    strncpy(str,token,v);
    str[v] = '\0';
    strcat(str,strA);
    strcat(str,token+v);

    strncpy(strC,str,x);
    strC[x] = '\0';
    strcat(strC,strB);
    strcat(strC,str+x);

    strncpy(strD,strC,y);
    strD[y] = '\0';
    strcat(strD,strB);
    strcat(strD,strC+y);

    strncpy(date_str,strD,z);
    date_str[z] = '\0';
    strcat(date_str,strA);
    strcat(date_str,strD+z);    

        fprintf(fileName, "%s", "\"date\": ");
        fprintf(fileName,"%s", date_str);
     }

      token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
      ++counter;
   }
}
```

I would be gratefull if somebody could help me.

Comment: why don't you just combine the two tokens then?

Comment: @picador: with e.g. `strcat`.

Comment: I know that I can use strcat but I do not know where on my code becase the variable values are only accesible inside the if statments.

Comment: What `DELIMITER__` are you using?

Comment: I am using "," The most important is that when count==1 the value from  token=112050.359 and when count==9 the value from token=080216. Please I need help printing both values in the same output string

Comment: you already parse your tokens into two variables: `time_str` and `date_str`, instead of printing them upon parsing in the loop, combine and print them after parsing both tokens (i.e. after the loop). Try it for yourself first, it'll help you so much more than if someone gives you a complete code example

Comment: Could you please provide the following code on an answer?@BeyelerStudios But how can I combine them if the values are only accesibles inside the if?

Comment: Thank you very much! @BeyelerStudios

Answer (score 1):

Parse `time_str` and `date_str` first, then print them out:

```
void tokenize(char *oneline, FILE *fileName) {
    const char delimiter[6] = DELIMITER__;
    char time_str[50];
    char date_str[50];
    char *token;
    int counter = 0;
    /* parse time and date */
    for(token = strtok(oneline, delimiter);
            token != NULL;
            token = strtok(NULL, delimiter), ++counter)
    {
        if(counter == 1) {
            char *strA = "\"", *strB = ":", str[50], strC[50], strD[50];
            int v = 0, x = 3, y = 6, z=13;
            strncpy(str,token,v);
            str[v] = '\0';
            strcat(str,strA);
            strcat(str,token+v);
            strncpy(strC,str,x);
            strC[x] = '\0';
            strcat(strC,strB);
            strcat(strC,str+x);
            strncpy(strD,strC,y);
            strD[y] = '\0';
            strcat(strD,strB);
            strcat(strD,strC+y);
            strncpy(time_str,strD,z);
            time_str[z] = '\0';
            strcat(time_str,strA);
            strcat(time_str,strD+z);        
        } else if (counter == 9) {
            char *strA = "\"", *strB = "-", str[50], strC[50], strD[50];
            int v = 0, x = 3, y = 6, z=9;
            strncpy(str,token,v);
            str[v] = '\0';
            strcat(str,strA);
            strcat(str,token+v);
            strncpy(strC,str,x);
            strC[x] = '\0';
            strcat(strC,strB);
            strcat(strC,str+x);
            strncpy(strD,strC,y);
            strD[y] = '\0';
            strcat(strD,strB);
            strcat(strD,strC+y);
            strncpy(date_str,strD,z);
            date_str[z] = '\0';
            strcat(date_str,strA);
            strcat(date_str,strD+z);        
        }
    }
    if(counter < 10) {
        /* handle error case */
    } else {
        fprintf(fileName,"\"date\": %s %s", time_str, date_str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagine that insteed of saving the values in an output file I want to save them in a char[2000]. How can I do that?

Comment: @picador use `sprintf` instead of `fprintf`